# How to handle a POST request with a Servlet API

Tags: java, api, servlets, jax-rs

I am trying to make an API with Jetty Server, and I have this simple GET request:

```
@GET
public String helloWorld(){
    return "Hello world";
}
```

In order to make a `POST` request, I assume that one must save the input to the Jetty server. I have tried to research for quite a while, but found nothing.

I imagine something like this:

```
@POST
public void Save(String stringToSave) {
    // Save to DB?
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very Jetty specific.  I would say this is either Servlet or JAX-RS specific.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you, it probably relates to one of those then

Comment: You're asking about the servlet API but posting JAX-RS code - what do you need help with?

Comment: @stdunbar I am not experienced enough to know. What code snippet do you need from me, if you were to analyze if I need help with JAX-RS or servlet API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could likely google this but let me give you a quick overview.  A [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) is a chunk of code that is normally run during an HTTP action - GET, POST, etc.  It is the original technology of the JavaEE world, having been released in the late 1990's.

A simple Java servlet, using modern annotations, would look something like:

```
@WebServlet(name = "SampleServlet", urlPatterns = "/sampleServlet")
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // called when an HTTP POST is sent
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // called when an HTTP GET is sent
    }
}
```

The important parts to note are that the class extends `HttpServlet` and that you have  to write code to pull data out of the request and push it into the response.  This isn't bad to do but it does have to be done.

[JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) is a newer standard, aimed simplifying the creation of REST services.  It too is a chunk of code that runs during an HTTP interaction.

A simple example of this would be:

```
@Path("/sampleService")
public class SampleService{
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @POST
    @Path("/v1/hello")

    public Response sayHello( SomeObject someobject ) {
```

The code here is both simpler and a bit more complex.  The use of annotations helps determine the path that the service exists on a URL (in this case `/sampleService/v1/hello`), the HTTP method, and the `Content-Type` for both the request and response.  Additionally, if the `SomeObject` object is defined correctly, the JAX-RS framework will automatically deserialize the incoming JSON or XML payload into an object for you.

The `Response` object contains the HTTP response code (perhaps a teapot) and a response body.  In this example, the body will be automatically serialized back to the requestor in a way that matches the `Accept` header of the HTTP request (i.e., JSON for an `application/json` Accept header and XML for `application/xml`).

Note that while not directly related the JAX-RS framework takes advantage of the Servlet framework.  Indeed in JAX-RS you can access the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` object in your methods.

Which way is "better"?  In general I would recommend using JAX-RS where possible as it is the newer standard and is a bit easier to implement.  However, if you do any work in the JavaEE world you're very likely to run into Servlet code so it's important to understand it too.

Note that both Servlets and JAX-RS require an application server of some sort.  Jetty is one of those. Another very common one is Tomcat.  The application server sets up the environment for your code and listens for incoming HTTP messages.  When it gets one it looks to see if it knows how to handle the URL and routes to the appropriate place.  In the servlet world the server routes solely on the URL.  In the JAX-RS world the server routes on the URL and, if specified by the `@Consumes` annotation, the HTTP `Content-Type` header too.

There is much more but let's start there and see if it answers what you're after.

Comment: This is very useful. I'm honestly very grateful that you took the time to write such an elaborate answer. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't really have a chance to check SO until now. All I can say is that I really appreciate your time and help, this was a helpful read.

Comment: I have a follow up question, if I may. Does a server, such as Jetty, make use of servlets to create the server? I have a chunk of code that uses, among others, `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server`, `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;`, `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;` and other class imports to create a server, e.g. `Server server = new Server(threadPool);`

Comment: That looks like [embedded Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) code.  That means that instead of having a pre-built environment you can create the server yourself.  But no, embedded servers may be able to *run* servlets but the servlet spec has nothing to do with creating the server directly.